# Evaluating Test set using Weka

Tags: classification, weka

I have 34 feature training set which after the feature selection only 10 best features were considered. I saved the model and tried to revaluate the test set with the model trained. There is always a pop up saying the test set and training set does not match , One thing is the test set contains all the 34 parameters and i even tried deleting all the other parameters apart from the selected ones, still some error occurs and i am not satisfied with the results so pls help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

The feature selection process must be applied to the test set as well. You can do this by using the batch option (`-b`) in the Command Line Interface. Just type the following command to get the options:

```
java weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection -b -h
```

Here is an example, [adapted from this post](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/language-identification-as-text.html).

```
java weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection -E \\
weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval \\
-S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T 0.0" \\
-b -i training.arff -o training.ig0.arff -r test.arff -s test.ig0.arff
```